# Space between menu items

Tags: html, css, formatting

I'm trying to make menu on top bar but I want to make a little bit of space between each element. How can I make some space between each menu item?

```css
.TopMenu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px
}
```

```html
<div class="TopMenu">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Inicio</a>
  <a href="#tecnologias">Tecnologias Que Trabajamos</a>
  <a href="#labs">Labs</a>
  <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
  <a href="#legal">Legal</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a flexbox container you can use the [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) attribute on your flex element as follows:

```
.TopMenu {
  gap: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add some styling to the `a` links. Adding `:not(:first-of-type)` makes sure this will only happen from the second item and onward

```
.TopMenu a:not(:first-of-type) {
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just switch `justify-content` to `space-between`

```css
.TopMenu{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 50%;
height: 40px;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="TopMenu">
        <a class="active" href="#home">Inicio</a>
        <a href="#tecnologias">Tecnologias Que Trabajamos</a>
        <a href="labs">Labs</a>
        <a href="contacto">Contacto</a>
        <a href="#legal">Legal</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

See it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/weghauok/)

Comment: There's no need to use jsfiddle; just use the "Copy snippet to answer" button....